# Optimizing RAM usage when training a learning model

Tags: python, deep-learning, ram, rdp

I have been working on creating and training a Deep Learning model for the first time. I did not have any knowledge about the subject prior to the project and therefor my knowledge is limited even now.

I used to run the model on my own laptop but after implementing a well working OHE and SMOTE I simply couldnt run it on my own device anymore due to MemoryError (8GB of RAM). Therefor I am currently running the model on a 30GB RAM RDP which allows me to do so much more, I thought.

My code seems to have some horribly inefficiencies of which I wonder if they can be solved. One example is that by using pandas.concat my model's RAM usages skyrockets from 3GB to 11GB which seems very extreme, afterwards I drop a few columns making the RAm spike to 19GB but actually returning back to 11GB after the computation is completed (unlike the concat). I also forced myself to stop using the SMOTE for now just because the RAM usage would just go up way too much.

At the end of the code, where the training happens the model breaths its final breath while trying to fit the model. What can I do to optimize this?

I have thought about splitting the code into multiple parts (for exmaple preprocessing and training) but to do so I would need to store massive datasets in a pickle which can only reach 4GB (correct me if I'm wrong). I have also given thought about using pre-trained models but I truely did not understand how this process goes to work and how to use one in Python.

P.S.: I would also like my SMOTE back if possible

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: How many categories do you have that the OHE encodes? Maybe it would help to show some code, for example what are you doing with the concatenation?

Comment: the original table has 7 columns, 3 of which I OHE encode. In total these three columns have around 5400 categories. The concatenation is used to add the OHE encoded columns back to the original column (because of the 4 remaining columns that didnt get encoded) and the "drop" command is used directly afterwards to get rid of the unencoded categorial columns.

Comment: This part of the code looks like this:

https://pastebin.com/jtxbTv1C

Sorry if it looks like a mess. I'm really not known in the field of efficient coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's analyze the steps:

Step 1: OHE
For your OHE, the only dependence there is between data points is that it needs to be clear what categories are there overall. So the OHE can be broken into two steps, both of which do not require that all data points are in RAM.

Step 1.1: determine categories
Stream read your data points, collecting all the categories. It is not necessary to save the data points you read.

Step 1.2: transform data
After step 1.1, each data point can be independently converted. So stream read, convert, stream write. You only need one or very few data points in memory at all times.

Step 1.3: feature selection
It may be worthwile to look at feature selection to reduce the memory footprint and improve performance. This [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/321993/27854) argues it should happen before SMOTE.

Feature selection methods based on entropy depend on all data. While you can probably also throw something together which streams, one approach that worked well for me in the past is removing features that only one or two data points have, since these features definitely have low entropy and probably don't help the classifier much. This can be done again like Step 1.1 and Step 1.2

Step 2: SMOTE
I don't know SMOTE enough to give an answer, but maybe the problem has already solved itself if you do feature selection. In any case, save the resulting data to disk so you do not need to recompute for every training.

Step 3: training
See if the training can be done in batches or streaming (online, basically), or simply with less sampled data.

With regards to saving to disk: Use a format that can be easily streamed, like csv or some other splittable format. Don't use pickle for that.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly orthogonal to your actual question, if your high RAM usage is caused by having entire dataset in memory for the training, you could eliminate such memory footprint by reading and storing only one batch at a time: read a batch, train on this batch, read next batch and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I see how this would make sense but I do have some follow up questions. If I dont read my data all at once or at least have it in my memory all at once than would something like a SMOTE still be possible? Also assuming this isn't possible, I am wondering if a badly balanced category has even less influence if you choose smaller batches.